# Expanding div using javascript and css transitions

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have a section with some text that I want to animate out when you click on it. Here is the jsfiddle link below, the html and css is pretty straightforward. Can anybody explain to me why its not working?

http://jsfiddle.net/jtKuZ/9/

My javascript code looks like:

```
function show-hide(element)
{
    var classname = document.getElementById(element).className;
    if (classname == "hidden")
        document.getElementById(element).className = "visible";
    else
        document.getElementById(element).className = "hidden";
}
```

And I have this in my HTML:

```
<div id="container">
<div id="content" class="hidden" onclick="show-hide('content');">
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet...
</div>
</div>
```

Comment: `-` is not allowed in function names. This would be a good time to learn how the [JavaScript error console](http://www.netmagazine.com/tutorials/javascript-debugging-beginners) works.

Comment: Good idea, I'm just starting out in javascript. Thanks.

Comment: Even if I change the function, it does not work in jsfiddle. Why? http://jsfiddle.net/jtKuZ/23/

Comment: You need to set the JS to load without wrappers (second pull-down menu on the left), otherwise the function is not in scope. http://jsfiddle.net/jtKuZ/24/

Answer (score 1):

I would prefer jQuery for this:

It makes your life a lot easier:

```
$('#content').on('click', function() {
    $(this).toggleClass("visible");

    if($(this).is('.visible'))
        $(this).animate({left: 0}, 1000);
    else
        $(this).animate({left: '490px'}, 1000);
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/Recode/jtKuZ/14/

Comment: I like the simplicity over creating separate css classes, +1